# Azure Application Gateway private ip dns resolution

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

Is it possible for the private frontend ip of a V2 Application Gateway to be resolved from the internal vnet dns?

Comment: Can you please share more details. What is mean by internal vnet DNS? There are 3 different options for DNS resolution in a VNET i.e. `Azure-Provided Name resolution (default)`, `Azure DNS Private Zones` & `OWN DNS server`. Which one you are referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Private DNS Zone and link that to the Application Gateway VNET and add a A record pointing to Application Gateway's Private IP.

So, VMs can resolve to the the Application Gateway Private IP.

You can either go with Private DNS Zone or use you own custom DNS config. Your ask is possible.

Regards,
Msrini

Comment: Thanks for the response and this looks like the correct answer to my question. Unfortunately I've asked a slightly simpler question than I need. I'd like to resolve this DNS entry for the application gateway from across a P2S VPN connection. Can you suggest a way of using the private DNS entry from across the P2S connection as I don't think it will work OOTB.

Comment: It is not possible by using Azure services as of today, You can manually add a hostname entry in your client machine pointing to AppGW frontend IP as a workaround.